Induction proof on a linear function
Am I on the right track with my attempt at the following problem?

Show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq 8$ there exist $k, l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=3  k+5  l$.
Hint: Use not only $n=8$ for the induction base.


Base case
$n = 8:$
$3\cdot1 + 5\cdot1 = 8$
$n + 1 = 9:$
$3\cdot1 + 5\cdot 1 + 1 = 9$
Induction step
Assume $n = 3k + 5l$   and $n+1 = 3k' + 5l'$
Claim: for $n + 2$ there exist some $k''$ and $l''$ such that $3k'' + 5l'' = n+2$
$3(k'-k) + 5(l'-l) -1 = n$
$3(k'-k) + 5(l'-l) +1 = n + 2$

Thank you in advance

Does this answer your question? Proof that $n = 3k + 5l$ for $n > 7$ - found using an Approach0 search. FYI, there are other duplicates, e.g., Strong Induction: Every natural number $n\geq 8$ can be represented as $n=3k + 5\ell$, and other closely related questions involving the Frobenius Coin problem.

You haven't solve the base case $n=9.$

@JohnOmielan Yes, it does. I wasn't aware of Approach0 search . Thanks for introducing it here. Next time I try searching there before posting.
